# Required Input in a JS Quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript Q&A Quiz working but I have one issue that must be solved.
I need to make the answer required before going to the next question, I really don't know how to make this work.

I got this code from this source, but I have changed a few things. https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/GmPjjL

HTML:

```
 <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
    <button id="next">Next Question</button>
    <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "Question 1",
      answers: {
        a: "answer a",
b: "answer b", 
      },
      correctAnswer: "a"
    },
      {
      question: "question 2",
      answers: {
      a: "answer a",
b: "answer b", 

      },
      correctAnswer: "a"
    }

  ];

  function buildQuiz() {
    const output = [];

    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      const answers = [];

      for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
        answers.push(
          `<label>
             <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
           </label>`
        );
      }

     output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
           <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
    });

    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
  }

  function showResults() {
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");

    let numCorrect = 0;

    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;

        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "#333333";
      } else {
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "#333333";
      }
    });

    var premio;
    if(numCorrect == 0)
    {
        premio = '<div><span style="color: red">RESULT 0</span></div>'; } 
      else if(numCorrect == 1) {        premio = '<div>RESULT 1</div>'; } 

    document.getElementById("quiz").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("previous").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `RESULT <span class="resultadonum">${numCorrect}</span>` + premio; //de ${myQuestions.length}//
  }

  function showSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
    slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function showNextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById("results");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  buildQuiz();

  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  showSlide(0);

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
})();
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question a little?  E.g., the fact that it's a quiz isn't really relevant to the information you need to answer your question.  Also, I see there is no jQuery or other, so perhaps you could mention "plain Javascript" in the question.  Things like that will clarify what you're seeking, and will help search engines find this question if other people have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute for your button.

Hook the disabled up to a function that checks whether or not the user has entered anything. Review your answers container around line 77 for the relevant code to check if the user has entered anything.

Psudo Code

```
function checkIfUserEnteredAnything(currentSlide){
    //Code to calculate how many questions total the user has answered.
    if(currentSlide === numQuestionsUserAnswered){
        return true}
    return false
```

Then, you'll set up your button to be disabled if the user hasn't entered anything.

```
nextButton.setAttribute('disabled',!checkIfUserEnteredAnything(currentSlide))
```

The exclamation point denotes the "not" function; if your function returns true (the user *has* entered a value), then it will become false-- telling the next button that it should not be disabled. If your function returns false, then the user has NOT entered a value, and it will tell the button to be disabled.